# Reference a different column in that same table

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to have a column in a table reference a different column in that same table? Here is my situation:

I'm trying to create a database in my table to store comments. Some of my columns are `CommentID`, `UserID`, `ParentID`, `Content`.

`CommentID` is the `IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` and `UserID` references the `User` table. `ParentID` basically will form the hierarchy for the comments. It should reference `CommentID`. Is there a way to reference `CommentID` or to ensure that the value for `ParentID` equals a record where that is matched?

### Data

```
Comment ID     ParentID     Content
-----------------------------------------
1              NULL         Love It!
2              1            That's a stupid comment.
3              2            No, you left the stupid comment.
4              1            Wow, much thanks!
5              4            Seriously?
```

I also have a timestamp column which will further sort the comments. I'm not even sure if I need to add any special key, I just don't want to run into trouble down the road. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a column in a table reference another in the same table. In your case creating a foreign key constraint from ParentID to CommentID would be perfectly OK.

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (
   CommentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
   ParentID INT,
   Comment VARCHAR(MAX),
   FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Comments(CommentID)
)

INSERT INTO Comments (CommentID, ParentID, Comment) VALUES (1, NULL, 'First Comment')

INSERT INTO Comments (CommentID, ParentID, Comment) VALUES (2, NULL, 'Second Comment')

INSERT INTO Comments (CommentID, ParentID, Comment) VALUES (3, 1, 'Sub Comment')

INSERT INTO Comments (CommentID, ParentID, Comment) VALUES (4, 3, 'Sub Sub Comment')

-- The following will fail with constraint violation
INSERT INTO Comments (CommentID, ParentID, Comment) VALUES (5, 10, 'Invalid Sub Comment 2')
```